# Check if background value exists for JXA/Applescript for Numbers

Tags: applescript, javascript-automation

I'm using JavasScript to write the script for Numbers automation. I believe its called JXA in this context? Based on: https://leancrew.com/all-this/2022/05/javascript-vs-applescript/

Anyway here's a function that colorize the row based on a condition:

```js
function colorize(row) {
  const blue = [22085.295, 49609.995, 65535]

  const rs = row.cells[2].value()?.indexOf('PRUDENTIAL')

  if (foundAndDefined(rs)) {
    console.log(row.backgroundColor);
    row.backgroundColor = blue
  }
}
```

However, I don't want to override the color if a color is already defined.

But trying to `console.log` the backgroundColor throws `Error -1700: Can't convert types.`

How can we check if there's any existing value or `console.log` the value if any?

Comment: JXA is riddled with defects and omissions, and very dead and abandoned. AppleScript, while awful, at least works right. Write your script in AppleScript: if you can get it to work there, it means you ran into an unfixed (unfixable) JXA bug and you should stick to AS. If you can’t get it to work in AS either, post back here with a runnable AppleScript example and the error message AS gives you, and folks can help you figure out if the problem is with your script or if it’s something Numbers doesn’t support/is broken.

Comment: Thanks, managed to figure it out and posted the solution. Yes, I find AppleScript more convoluted than JS/JXA too. Will try to avoid AS as long as JXA isn't giving me trouble.

Comment: If you enjoy living dangerously: [nodeautomation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeautomation). It descends from appscript, which also works right and supports/ed languages that don’t suck. I don’t provide [unpaid] support, and there might be the odd bug; but the free ASDictionary and ASTranslate tools answer 96% of the “How do I…” questions and, while its documentation is crusty and not great, it is still far better than any of Apple’s. Plus, it’s Node.js so you have access to all of its vast libraries, tools, and other resources. Night and Day. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out, simply call backgroundColor as a function like `backgroundColor()`.

Full example:

```js
function colorize(row) {
  const blue = [22085.295, 49609.995, 65535]

  const rs = row.cells[2].value()?.indexOf('PRUDENTIAL')

  if (foundAndDefined(rs)) {
    if (isNull(row.backgroundColor())) row.backgroundColor = blue
  }
}
```

Where `isNull` is a custom function not shown